# Limit on how many candies you will receive?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been playing Pokemon Go since its release and have utilized the *"Transfer"* option to my advantage (to increase the level of my other Pokemon). However, I have only seen one candy being dropped every time I transfer a Pokemon to the Professor. Is the maximum amount of candy you can obtain from a Pokemon 1, or are there factors that enable you to gain more than one candy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Every Pokemon you transfer will only give you 1 candy when you're transferring it. Even when that Pokemon is evolved.

When you catch a Pokemon you will always get 3 candies.

When you get a Pokemon from an [egg](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Egg), you normally get a much higher number of candies with it for free. Compare this table, from a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4ws4dl/results_from_egg_research_egg_distance_does_in/):

```
 2 km eggs:  5 to 15 candy
 5 km eggs: 10 to 21 candy
10 km eggs: 16 to 32 candy
```

Comment: You also get 1 candy each time a Pokemon is evolved. So an evolve then transfer gives two.

Answer (score 3):

You always get one candy for transferring Pokemon, there is nothing like a "Power-Up" to change this.

Answer (score 2):

You get varying amounts of candy when hatching an egg, 3 pieces when catching a Pokemon, and 1 piece when transferring a Pokemon.

Comment: While your answering is correct, it's really adding nothing that wasn't already mentioned.

Comment: This is not actually correct, eggs will return a variable number of candies.  I personally have seen as low as 4-5 and as high as 21.

Answer (score 2):

Well you do get 3 candies for a caught Pokemon and 1 for a transfer but the amount u get from an egg varies. For example I've gotten 6 from my last egg but 15 from the one before.

Answer (score 1):

3 for catching a pokemon
1 for transfering
the higher level the egg generally the more candies but it is still extremely variable,   I have gotten 21 candies from a 5km hatch yet only 15 from a 10km hatch so it just depends on your roll of the dice.

Answer (score 0):

3 on catching and
1 on transfering
Eggs candies depends upon km.
Be smart......